# I don’t know how best to put new data into a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**purpose**

Add a new Name and Color object to the state.book array without removing the past data

.push is not allowed. you cannot mutate the state and it puzzled me

The second day I struggle with the task :(

Thank you in advance

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  book: [
    {
      name: "Name",
      color: "#5236C1",
      list: [
        {
          title: "Author",
          about: "Created by.",
          imgLink: "link",
          url: "linkRead"
        }
     }
  ] 
};
const newcat = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CATEGORY":
      return AddCategory(state, action.title, action.color);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default newcat;
```

***Test***

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addCat } from "../actions/addCat";
const Test = () => {
  const store = useSelector((state) => state.newcat);
  console.log(store);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const clickHandler = () => {
    let title = "A";
    let color = "#325125";
    dispatch(addCat(title, color));
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

**Action**

```
export const addCat = (title, color) => ({
        type: 'ADD_CATEGORY',
        title,
        color
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer file use this:

```
const newcat = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case "ADD_CATEGORY":
    return {...state, book:[...state.book, {color:action.color, title:action.title}]
  default:
    return state;
}};
```

Can you elaborate the data structure you are trying to add. I am a bit confused as the book array consists of the books array which are objects with a color attribute, and then a list of objects which has title attribute. Do you want to create a new book object with it's own list items or mutate the existing book list item.

Also instead of passing individual attributes in the action it is best practice to send them as a payload.

The following changes would be enough to achieve this.

---

**Action**

```
export const addCat = (title, color) => ({
    type: 'ADD_CATEGORY',
    payload : {title, color}
});
```

---

**Reducer**

```
const newcat = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case "ADD_CATEGORY":
    const {color, title} = action.payload
    return {...state, book:[...state.book, {color, title}]
  default:
    return state;
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question the push operation results in mutation of the array. This is because, for example, we have an array say

```
let list = [1,2,3];
list.push(4) //The output will be a list [1,2,3,4];
```

But here no new array is returned and the original array is being updated. This change in the original element is mutation.

So another way where we can insert the element without mutating the original array is to use the spread operator.

```
let list = [1,2,3];
let updatedList = [...list,4];//Now list remains unchanged and updatedList will be [1,2,3,4]
```

Here the original element list remains unchanged. In the particular reducer method mentioned above the updation of the state could be as follows

(Assuming that the books array of the state object contains the categories of books and the list inside the object inside book array contains the books under the particular category,The title and color in the dispatched action corresponds to name and color of the category of the book)

```
function AddCategory(state,title, color){
 return {...state,books:[...state.books,{name:title,color:color,list:[]}]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Good luck!